# How to provide relative sizes in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I have a Box layout and I want to layout child views relative to the size of the parent box. This is achievable in SwiftUI using Geometry Reader. How can I achieve something similar in Jetpack Compose ?

Comment: Use a `Row` or a `Column` instead of a `Box` and apply the `Modifier.weight`

Comment: I have to use Box as I need to stack multiple CircularProgressIndicator views with different sizes. There is no weight option in Box to use.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `BoxWithConstraints` instead of a `Box`.
You can work with the [measurement constraints](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/BoxWithConstraintsScope) available in the scope of the content lambda.

Something like:

```
BoxWithConstraints {
    Box(Modifier.width(maxWidth*0.7f).height(30.dp).background(Color.Blue))
    Box(Modifier.width(maxWidth*0.3f).height(30.dp).background(Color.Yellow))
}
```

[image]

Otherwise you can use the `Box` and `fillMaxWidth` and `fillMaxHeight` modifiers with a fraction.

```
Box(){
    Box(Modifier.fillMaxWidth(0.7f).height(30.dp).background(Color.Blue))
    Box(Modifier.fillMaxWidth(0.3f).height(30.dp).background(Color.Yellow))
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I was able to accomplish it by using onGloballyPositioned on Box's Modifier.