# Does Jetpack Compose have maxHeight and maxWidth like XML?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm looking to have a LazyColumn that initially wraps content height, but if it gets to a certain height (232dp) then it fixes its height at this. In XML I would have used maxHeight combined with wrapContent, but I cant find anything similar in Compose?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You can use `heightIn` modifier on `LazyColumn` like this

```
LazyColumn(
    modifier = Modifier
        .heightIn(0.dp, 232.dp) //mention max height here 
        .widthIn(0.dp, 232.dp) //mention max width here 
) {                     
}
```

This will make sure that the height will not go above 232.dp if more items are added to `lazycolumn`

Comment: Is it possible to set maxWidth by fraction?

Comment: @JacobFerrero Use `BoxWithConstraints` https://stackoverflow.com/a/67846893/830988

Comment: @JacobFerrero use onGloballyPositioned in parent layout to get max width in px, convert it to dp, save to mutableStateOf and pass it to widthIn with some multiplier e.g. 0.7f for max 70 % width

Answer (score 2):

To set a max height by a fraction of the parent element, usigng onGloballyPositioned as suggested by @goofy, this worked for me:

```js
var columnSize by remember { mutableStateOf(Size.Zero) }
// This is the parent element, a Column in this example
// but it can be any other composable
Column(
    Modifier
        // Forcing it to fill the available space, but
        // it may also have a limited size.
        .fillMaxSize() 
        .onGloballyPositioned { layoutCoordinates ->
            columnSize = layoutCoordinates.size.toSize()
        }
) {
   // Setting the maximum height to 50% of the parent
    var maxHeight = LocalDensity.current.run {(0.5f*columnSize.height).toDp()}
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier.heightIn(0.dp, maxHeight),
    ) {
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you can achieve the same effect by putting the composable you want to constrain inside a `Box` with a `fillMax[Width|Height|Size]` modifier with a weight argument (i.e. the percentage you want to occupy). Imo, that layout hack should be avoided at all cost since it can cause layout instability especially on slow devices.